# How can I populate an HTML dropdown with data from a database using Django?

Tags: python, django

I'm attempting to create a dropdown selection on an HTML page containing options (specifically, the userID and name of a character for the user to select to load into a battle simulator) from my database, but it keeps coming up empty without any errors or any indication as to what is wrong. I'm trying to base my solution off of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6063081/12352379). I know using a ModelForm through Django is an option, but if all I'm doing is populating HTML fields, I'm not sure if it would be my best option to take the time needed to familiarize with ModelForm. Below is what I presently have:

views.py:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import TemplateView # Import TemplateView
from django.http import HttpResponse
from pathfinder.models import characterTable

[...]
class battleSimView(TemplateView):
    template_name = "battleSim.html"

    def post(request):
       item  = characterTable.objects.all() # use filter() when you have sth to filter ;)

       return render_to_response (self.template_name, {'items':item}, context_instance =  RequestContext(request),)
[...]
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class characterTable(models.Model):
    userID = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    playerName = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    race = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    playerClass = models.CharField(max_length = 32)
    strength = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    dexterity = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    constitution = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    intelligence = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    wisdom = models.CharField(max_length = 2)
    charisma = models.CharField(max_length = 2)

    def __str__(self):
        return (self.userID + ": " + self.playerName )
[...]
```

form area of battleSim.html, in my templates folder

```html
[...]
    <form method="POST">
      <select name="item_id">
      {% for entry in items %}
          <option value="{{ entry.userID }}">{{ entry.playerName }}</option>
      {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </form>
[...]
```

What I am attempting to do is use the POST call in the HTML Form to call the post function in views.py, which ideally in my head would render the page and pass the items from my Model through as parameters, which the HTML page can then use in the dropdown. Do I need a GET function somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully, your problem will solve with this question and the answers,

[click the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46189233/how-to-post-my-html-form-to-django-model-and-save-it)